# How to make a mathematical function plotter with Tkinter with inputs?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a Tkinter software where you can input the x, y and z components of a vector field then display the results with matplotlib.

I managed to build the GUI and to display various fields but by defining them in the source code. Is it possible to make it so you can input the equations in the GUI and then have it displayed ?

These are the ideas I had :

- Input Numpy commands as strings then transform the input into source code somehow ?
- Input Latex and use that if possible haha.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: "Input Numpy commands as strings then transform the input into source code somehow ?" - this is possible: see https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#eval. Using this function isn't safe because it lets the user execute arbitrary Python code, but I guess it's not terribly important or harmful here

Comment: I heard about that but wasn't sure, thank you for your insights !